# Implement fuzzy search in the Google Maps Text Search API

Tags: google-places-api

Is there any way that the Google Text Search Place API can perform a fuzzy search on the search suggestions? It seems like it only returns those results that are exactly matched with the search input string.

I have read through the documentation and I didn't find anything regarding this. Any help in this matter will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What would be your use case for the fuzzy search? It would be quite understandable why fuzzy search is not a feature of the text search API because it's main purpose is to provide an accurate search result in the first place.